# What is the meaning of the proverb in 1 Samuel 10:12?

Tags: 1-samuel

In the Book of 1st Samuel we read:

> **1 Samuel 10:12**: "A man there said, 'Now, who is their father?' Therefore it became a proverb: '*Is Saul also among the prophets?*'" (emphasis added).

What does this proverb mean? Is there a method by which we can discern what was originally intended by this phrase?

Comment: Are the preceding three verses not clear enough ?

Answer (score 1):

1 Samuel 10:12:

> "A man there said, 'Now, who is their father?' Therefore it became a proverb: 'Is Saul also among the prophets?'"

What does this proverb mean?

Benson:

> Hence it became a proverb — Used when any **strange** or unexpected thing happened.

Matthew Poole

> It became a proverb, used when any **strange**, unlikely, or unexpected thing happened.

Keil and Delitzsch

> a proverb which was used to express astonishment at the appearance of any man in a sphere of life which had hitherto been altogether **strange** to him.

Is there a method by which we can discern what was originally intended by this phrase?

I stick to the method of Occam's Razor: pick the simplest explanation.
In this case, the consensus among Bible commentators is the simple explanation that the new proverb/saying "Is Saul also among the prophets?" means "something strange/funny is going on".